Awesome notification module not found
I need assistance, I am trying to run my flutter app but it keeps failing due to this:
/Users/mac/Documents/Flutter Projects/Work/foax_mobile/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9 Module 'awesome_notifications' not found
The image attached describes what error shows while running the build, how do i go about solving this:

Some things to check:
My guess-->

Did you started xcode by double clicking the
"runner.xcworkspace" from your "project/ios" folder and not
"runner.xcodeproj"?

-Did you have it in pubspec.yaml if you have dependecy there?
dependencies:
   awesome_notifications: ^0.10.0

-Did you imported the package?
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';


All the checks have been done
